# Allow users only certain information from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security

I have a database of information for 100 or so users. I have 2 MySQL users that has permission to the database. root and also a specific database user "directory". User "directory" only has permission to run SELECT statements, nothing else.

Some of the information is sensitive to that user and I am using PHP as a proxy to detect which user they are before any SQL commands are ran, how can I append every SELECT statement to include `WHERE id = '$their_id'`  where `$their_id` is a php variable with their id.

Please note the users will have ability to write their PHP mysql commands, I am defining these restrictions in a db.php that will include the connection information.

I want to prevent say the user `joe` being able to run a command like `SELECT * WHERE id = 'bob'` when `joe` isn't `bob`.

---

Edit:

I currently do not scan-through any of the MySQL commands, I simply just create the connection for them in db.php. Is there anyway I can make my own proxy MySQL commands and force them to use them, that way they have to use my command `mysql_query` and not the default `mysql_query` to override any processing I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than modify their query just always have them reference the data through a view.  They have no rights at all to the real table the view is created over.  You create that view with

```
Create View tablenametheyuse as select * from realtable with id = 'user'
```

and only give that user authority to his view.

They now code their select statements any way they want over the view.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't seem very secure but I would just check every entry to see if the word 'id' is in it. Then check to see what it equals, if it isn't their user id then don't execute the command.

Comment: Seems easy enough, but see the update answer on how to force them to use the function that will process this

Comment: Well it looks like they are only inputting MYSQL queries. So you can just create your own function process_queries(query) and then when you're done editing it you can mysql_query(query)