# MySQL Temporary View possible?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, permissions, view

This is following up on:

[Allow users only certain information from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479025/allow-users-only-certain-information-from-database/5479078#5479078)

I am doing views as such (I am sure this could be optimized):

`db.php` that gets included:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","directory","dghgffhghf") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("directory", $conn) or die(mysql_error());  

mysql_query("CREATE or REPLACE VIEW {$user}_rooms AS SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE palace = '$user'") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_query("CREATE or REPLACE VIEW {$user}_users AS SELECT * FROM users WHERE palace = '$user'") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_query("CREATE or REPLACE VIEW {$user}_servers AS SELECT * FROM servers WHERE palace = '$user'") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_query("CREATE or REPLACE VIEW {$user}_online_servers AS SELECT * FROM online_servers WHERE palace = '$user'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Where the user "directory" has to have `SELECT`, `CREATE VIEW` and `DROP` permissions (`DROP` is required because of the `or REPLACE`). I do not want them to have `DROP` permissions , as the directory user will be in a PHP file owned by apache, and they arent restricted to it using `dir`- so they could just view the user and pass.

Also, I dont wan't a user to just use `bob_rooms` when he is actually `joe`. I only want the view to be created for ONLY that user at that specific connection, and DROP as soon as the connection is gone. I cannot rely on the user to `DROP` the view on their own.

Also, having a temporary view that would auto-drop would eliminate the use of `or REPLACE` which means I can take odd `DROP` permissions for the user.

I guess in SQLlite it would be as easy as:

```
CREATE TEMP VIEW ...
```

SqlLite can do temporary views, but MySQL can't?

Comment: Why do you need to drop them? It's not like they're static or anything (although I doubt the sanity of the plan to limit user access this way, or granting the right to write ones own SQL queries when they cannot be trusted).

Comment: Because if the views arent dropped them any user could view other user's info with just knowing their username. The idea is that the directory database contains information about their server. Some information is private. I am giving them access to their own information so they can use it in displaying information to their visitors.

Comment: What's the difference with now? They still can, they just have less time to do it..

Comment: I was hoping mySQL would have a temporary view much like a temporary table where only the connection that created the table can access that table. Therefore when they run their PHP file, a view/table will be made for them and they would have no access to anything else.

Comment: What would be amazing about a temporary view is that views can allow read/write

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about temporary views, but there is support for temporary tables. So you could do something where you create a temporary tables with the same structures as the tables they are mirroring, e.g. temp_bob_rooms for rooms. Then insert into the temp table a selection from the real table, with your appropriate restrictions, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO temp_bob_rooms (SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE user='bob');
```

Then when the user is done with his session, the temp table will be dropped automatically, so the directory user doesn't need DROP access any longer. You can read some more about temporary tables here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-temporary-tables.htm

The downside to this approach is that the temporary table won't be updated with data inserted into the 'real' table during the time the session with the temporary table is open.

Another approach might be to simply write a script that would generate a mysql user for each real user, the appropriate views, and grant permissions to those views to the appropriate users. The only downside to that approach is that your db.php file wouldn't be useful to anyone anymore, because each user would have to create his or her own connection with the correct password and user name.

Comment: A good 100 or so users make the mysql user idea a bit over the top. Also I did consider make temp tables but I would then have to give the user INSERT privileges, which is something I don't want them to have... Though I could limit non-access to the main tables... I might have to use this.

Comment: I haven't invested the time to research this idea proper, but one avenue to investigate would be taking the creation of the temp tables, the insertion, and place that into a stored procedure. Then the 'directory' user could be given access to just that procedure, and not given insert access.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a temporary table from a query in one step with the syntax:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table_name SELECT ... ;
```

The caveats to temporary tables:

- They aren't indexed-- large temporary tables don't perform well.
- They're only exist in the scope of the session which they're created.

Comment: The temporary tables can be indexed totally like usual, although you should ask for that to be done. It may have any index configuration not only for existing columns like `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (KEY smth(foo, bar)) SELECT ..., ... as foo, ... as bar, ... FROM ... ;`, but even new additional column and primary index with auto_increment on it may be declared: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp2 (new_pk INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY) AS SELECT tbl.* FROM tbl`. The `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT` case is reasonably enough described e.g. in MySQL manual.